# Debian Jessie : locales / unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, debian-jessie, dependencies

So I've got a VPS and, ***to be totally honest I have to admit, at some point I did a mess with apt sources and packages***. :)

Now I'm trying to get a clean system, almost there, but I still have a little problem : I can't install the package `locale`.

**My system :**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie


$ uname -r
2.6.32-042stab130.1
```

**And the problem :**

```
$ apt-get install locales
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 locales : Depends: libc-bin (> 2.19) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                    debconf-2.0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Although it seems I already have the right versions of these packages :**

```
$ apt-cache policy libc-bin
libc-bin:
  Installed: 2.25-6
  Candidate: 2.25-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.25-6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-18+deb8u10 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

$ apt-cache policy debconf 
debconf:
  Installed: 1.5.56+deb8u1
  Candidate: 1.5.56+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 1.5.56+deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Is there something I'm missing ?!

EDIT : And yes I did try `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean` and `apt-get -f install`. They all seem to execute without any error

Comment: You seem to have both version `2.25-6` AND `2.19-18+deb8u10` of the `libc-bin` package installed. This conflicts with the restraint `> 2.19` of the locale package. I guess removing the conflicting version would solve this, but I'm hesitant to recommend this, since I don't know what consequences this will have on other installed packages. You should at least check for installed packages which rely on that version first.

Comment: That seemed to be that, how do you see both are installed ? I though `***` and `100` codes were here to point the installed package(s). Although apparently that was still relying on some sources for a newer kernel (which I couldn't install on this VPS), so after some fights with `apt` I arrived at a critical point... `dpkg: warning: 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable` Woops ! And even... `-bash: touch: command not found`... Ok, time to ask for a clean system reinstall I think. :D